# Rails has_and_belongs_to with primary key delete all records on destroy

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've 3 models in Rails 5:

**Product**

```
 class Product < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :category
    has_and_belongs_to_many :stores

 end
```

**Store**

```
  class Store < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :admin_users
    has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
    has_and_belongs_to_many :products
  end
```

**ProductsStores**

```
  class ProductsStores < ApplicationRecord
    self.primary_key = :store_id
  end
```

When I try to delete one record of the join table **ProductsStores** with the command **ProductsStores.first.destroy** all records in the join table are destroyed. Why?

Could anyone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to understand differences between HABTM and has_many through:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association
If you created linkedin model and wanna using this model, you have to use `has_many through: association`, and add to this model `belongs_to :product` and `belongs_to :store`. Then with flag `dependent: :destroy` you will can destroy or not destroy linked models as default.